# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm setting up webpack to my react project using yarn and this error appears:

> ERROR in ./src/app.js 67:6 Module parse failed: Unexpected token
>   (67:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,
>   currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See
>   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>          ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules:[{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: '/\.(js|jsx)$/',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    }
}
```

```
.babelrc
{
    "presets": ["env", "react","@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the source for `app.js`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are using unnecessary escape character: which is not required.

**Replace** `test: '/\.(js|jsx)$/',` **with**  `test: /\.js$|jsx/,` it should work fine.

I replicated your issue in my machine and found the same which is resolved by the above fix.

hope this helps, happy coding!!!

Comment: That will match literally everything with the string `jsx` in it, even outside the file extension. OP's code is good except for the extra single quotes.

Answer (score 21):

The selected answer missing some details:

**It should be** `test: /\.js|\.jsx$/`

`\: is an escape character` in this case for `.`

`|: is an Alternation / OR operand`

`$: is end of line`

Hopefully this is useful for you.

Source:
https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Adding in jsx as well, threw an error.. `You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.`

Answer (score 2):

This error happened to me simply because the file was placed in the parent folder of the project (i.e. outside the project's folder).

Moving the file to the appropriate folder fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error while working on a file, before worrying about modifying webpack config, please check if the file leading to the error has an **extension** i.e **.js** or **.jsx**. I encountered this error when I forgot to add an extension on one of my Javascript files. i.e. instead of **my-file.js**, I had **my-file**

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I configure this and it works:

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
        presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: where to add this code in angular project?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a direct answer to the original question, but this is one of the most likely places people will end up when they are having trouble with a loader.

In my case the file that it was complaining about was inside of the node_modules folder. I was consuming a typescript file directly.

```
{
    test: /\.m?ts$|\.tsx?$/,
    // exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
        loader: "ts-loader",
        options: {
            onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
        }
    },
},
```

The change I made was removing the exclude portion and adding `onlyCompileBundledFiles` to `ts-loader`. Other loaders may have something similar. But basically it will only process items included in the bundle regardless of if they are inside or outside of the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Put the code mentioned below in webpack file**

```
mix.extend(
    "graphql",
    new (class {
        dependencies() {
            return ["graphql", "graphql-tag"];
        }

        webpackRules() {
            return {
                test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "graphql-tag/loader"
            };
        }
    })()
);


mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js").vue();

mix.graphql();
```

Comment: what is mix  ? would you please explain

Comment: I wonder we are not trying to add graphql loader here

Comment: it's working for Laravel and vue project

Answer (score -6):

add a .babelrc file to the same folder where your node_modules folder is, with the below content

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: I already have this file and yet I get the above error.

Comment: This does not resolve the issue.