# Lerna monorepo with Webpack issue of loading typescript files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lerna

I've setup a monorepo using Lerna and I've received the following error when trying to compile the application.

> ../template/src/App.tsx 4:9
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
| import React from 'react';
| 
> const App: React.FC = () => {
|     return (
|         <div className="App">
```

I've tried the solution in this question but it doesn't seem to work:

[You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924348/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-currently-no-loader)

Could you please shed some light on this potential issue?

I've attached a link to the full `webpack.config.js` file as it's rather large, but extrapolated the area where I anticipate the issue is from.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sound-uzmmm?file=/src/webpack.config.js

```
module: {
strictExportPresence: true,
rules: [
    { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
    {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
            {
                options: {
                    formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                    eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
                    emitWarning: isEnvDevelopment,
                },
                loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
            },
        ],
        include: [paths.appSrc, paths.packagesSrc, paths.sharedSrc],
    },
    {
        oneOf: [
            {
                test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
                loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
                options: {
                    limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                include: [paths.appSrc, paths.packagesSrc, paths.sharedSrc],
                loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                options: {
                    customize: require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'),
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
                    plugins: [
                        [
                            require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                            {
                                loaderMap: {
                                    svg: {
                                        ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]',
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    ],
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    cacheCompression: false,
                    compact: isEnvProduction,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
                exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
                loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                options: {
                    babelrc: false,
                    configFile: false,
                    compact: false,
                    presets: [[require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'), { helpers: true }]],
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    cacheCompression: false,
                    sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                    inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
            },
            {
                test: cssRegex,
                exclude: cssModuleRegex,
                use: getStyleLoaders({
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                }),
                sideEffects: true,
            },
            {
                test: cssModuleRegex,
                use: getStyleLoaders({
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                    modules: {
                        getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                    },
                }),
            },
            {
                test: sassRegex,
                exclude: sassModuleRegex,
                use: getStyleLoaders(
                    {
                        importLoaders: 3,
                        sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                    },
                    'sass-loader',
                ),
                sideEffects: true,
            },
            {
                test: sassModuleRegex,
                use: getStyleLoaders(
                    {
                        importLoaders: 3,
                        sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                        modules: {
                            getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                        },
                    },
                    'sass-loader',
                ),
            },
            {
                loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
                options: {
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                },
 

           },
            ],
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: In principle, there is no difference between a monorepo (using lerna or other tool) and an application with external NPM libraries.

Comment: I don't see ts-loader configured to support tsx files. ts-loader. Check more details https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader

Comment: @Xavier have you figured it out? facing the same issue